# Want to print combinations of elements of matrix in c

Tags: c, recursion, matrix, combinations

I have a 2d matrix 
and I want to print combinations of first row with rest rows

Here's what I have tried:

Since solution needs to be generic, i m priniting the loops and numbers using recursion.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int i,n,j,k,row=3,col=3,mat[10][10]={{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};

int printnumbers(int n,int i)
{
    if(n>=row)
    {
        n=0;
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("%d",mat[n][i]);
    printnumbers(n+1,i);
}

int printloop(int row,int col)
{
    //to check whether the function is being called first time. 
    if(row<=0)
        return 0;

    for(i=0;i<col;i++)
    {
        printloop(row-1,col);
        printnumbers(n,i);
    }        
}

int main()
{
    n=0;
    printloop(row,col);
}
```

But I m not able to come up with proper printing as desired, not able to think in depth for proper recursion.
The output of this code is:

```
147
258
369
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build the solution recursively. As your recursion goes deeper, you keep appending numbers of the respective matrix rows until you have picked a number from every row.

As you do so, you must keep track of the numbers you have already chosen for previous rows so you can print them.

Please, please don't make loop variables global. Ideally, don't use any global variables, but if you must, make them unique. In your example, `i`, `n`, `row` and `col` can either be locals or global variables, depending on context. It is very hard to see which variable a symbol really refers to.

Your `printnumbers` and `printloop` functions should either be `void` or return a meaningful value for all branches. Compiler warnings should tell you that you don't return anything when your execution reaches the end of the function.

Here's version that doesn't need global variables and that keeps the picked numbers in an auxiliary buffer `buf` that is allocated in the calling function.  It doesn't print the combination recursively, though.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printloop(int n, const int mat[n][n], int buf[n], int ix)
{
    int i;

    if (ix == n) {        
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf("%2d", buf[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            buf[ix] = mat[ix][i];
            printloop(n, mat, buf, ix + 1);
        }
    }    
}

int main()
{
    const int mat[3][3] = {
        {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}
    };
    int buf[3];

    printloop(3, mat, buf, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

(Note: As of C99, you can make the dimensions of an array variable when you pass them as a parameter. This parameter has to come before the array parameter.)

Comment: `buf` really is always the same buffer, because it is passed as a pointer to `buf` in main. It is repeatedly overwritten at position `ix` so that at the time of printing it contains the path  of the current recursion through the matrix. If you didn't store the path, the values picked before wouldn't be available at the time where you print the combo.

Comment: Then pass both dimensions and adjust the limits of the loops. I hope you know which is which.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is quite simple using **Slices** in **Golang**.

Making the solution above generic.

Here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func printElements(input [][]int, buf []int, row int, col int, count int) {
    var i int

    if (count == row) {
        for i=0; i<row; i++ {
            fmt.Print(buf[i])
        }
        fmt.Println() 
    } else {
        for i=0 ; i<col; i++ {
            buf[count] = input[count][i]
            printElements(input,buf,row,col,count+1)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var input = [][]int{{1,3,5}, {2,6,7}, {4,8,9}}

    row := len(input)
    col := len(input[0])

    var buf =  make([]int,col)

    printElements(input,buf,row,col,0)  
}
```

This is a generic solution depending on how you initialise the slice input.

See the output here: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lAVCd_9T7Z)

Thanks!